# Remove older duplicate row if the cells in two columns both match another row

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a worksheet that lists the Baseline, Product, and Version.

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows if Column "Product" and "Version" both match another row, ensuring the row retained is the latest BL (highest number released).

The logic I'm attempting:

```
IF cell values in Columns: "Product" & "Version":

    1. Both cells match another row
    2. AND "3" is in Column "Baseline" for that Product_Version
    THEN Remove duplicates for all other Baselines.

ELSEIF:

    1. Both cells match another row
    2. BUT Baseline "3" for that Product_Version is NOT present
    3. Baseline "2" is present.
    THEN Remove duplicates that aren't Basline "2".
```

My example data:

[image: Test Data]

Comment: Maybe it would be much better if you also attach the image of the expected result from your Test Data image. Is the expected result like this ? 0 - cat - 2.1 ... 1 - Dog - 1.1 ... 3 - Dog - 2.1 ... 2 - Pig - 3.1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, from the sample data in your image
[image]

My guess, your expected result is like this :
[image]

If my guess is correct and it's OK with you to have a temporary column for a helper, then maybe you can modify the code below according to your case.

```
Sub test()
Dim rgB As Range: Dim rgHelper As Range: Dim rgDel As Range
Dim cell As Range: Dim addr1 As String: Dim addr2 As String
Dim rg As Range: Dim arr: Dim el

With ActiveSheet
Set rg = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

'create temporary helper column and make a range as rgHelper variable
'then fill with concatenate value of column B and C
addr1 = Replace(rg(1, 1).Address, "$", "")
addr2 = Replace(rg(1, 2).Address, "$", "")
Set rgHelper = rg.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)
Set rgHelper = rgHelper.Resize(rg.Rows.Count, 1)
rgHelper.Value = "=concatenate(" & addr1 & "," & addr2 & ")"
rgHelper.Value = rgHelper.Value

'create unique value in rgHelper as arr variable
Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rgHelper: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next

'loop each element in arr as el variable
'set the range which has the looped el value as rgB variable
For Each el In arr
    With rgHelper
        .Replace el, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgB = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -4)
        .Replace True, el, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
'if rgB count is more than 1 then
'check if in rgB is found 3 then the BL is 3
'else if in rgB is found 2 then the BL is 2
    If Application.CountA(rgB) > 1 Then
        If Not rgB.Find(3, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            BL = 3
        ElseIf Not rgB.Find(2, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            BL = 2
        Else: BL = ""
        End If
        
'union the range to be deleted as rgDel variable
        If BL <> "" Then
            For Each cell In rgB
                If cell.Value <> BL Then
                    If rgDel Is Nothing Then
                        Set rgDel = Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight))
                    Else
                        Set rgDel = Union(rgDel, Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight)))
                    End If
                End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
Next el

'delete rgDel and clear rgHelper
rgDel.Delete Shift:=xlUp
rgHelper.Clear
End Sub
```

Because you don't mention another condition what if there is no 2 or 3 in Baseline column, so the code do nothing if it doesn't find 2 or 3. For example if Pig3.1 baseline is 4 and 5, then no process ---> Pig3.1 with baseline 4 still there, Pig3.1 with baseline 5 still there.

But you also mentioned :

> ensuring the row retained is the latest BL (**highest number released**).

If that's the case, doesn't it mean that the if condition has nothing to do with 2 and 3 ? For example :

- if duplicate Pig3.1 base line is 0 and 1, then the row to retain is Pig3.1 with
  baseline 1 ?
- if duplicate Dog2.1 baseline is 2, 3, 4, and 7, then the row to retain is
  Dog2.1 with baseline 7 ?

Please note, the code is just using 2 and 3 for comparison. It doesn't use the highest number of BL of the respective duplicate Product+Version.

Also, if for example duplicate Dog2.1 has baseline 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, it will delete Dog2.1 with baseline 1, 2, and 4. It will retain duplicate Dog2.1 with same baseline which is 3.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. I ended up being able to cleanup my data using a CustomOrder list to first set the latest baselines as the first displayed. Then I could cleanup matching Products_Versions using RemoveDuplicates. I would be interested in trying out this solution, since it seems it'll better future proof the problem I was trying to resovle. Thanks again!